# Oracle Disable Materialized View Refresh

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

Anyone have the syntax to disable the refresh of a materialized view in Oracle? I struggle with the Oracle documentation and I'm not finding an online example.

I understand it starts something like:
ALTER  MATERIALIZED VIEW view_name ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it is currently set to refresh on commit, you can change it to refresh on demand, which means you need to explcitly refresh it via `dbms_mview`, with:

```
alter materialized view view_name refresh on demand;
```

This seems fairly clear [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_2002.htm#i2233205).

If you really want to permanently disable refresh, even manually, so you're left with the current contents and they can not be updated from the view query, you can [drop the materialized view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_8021.htm#SQLRF01523) but keep the backing table:

```
drop materialized view view_name preserve table;
```

This is obviously more radical. And `view_name` will now just be an ordinary table, essentially as if you'd done `create table view_name as <view query>`.

Comment: Does the first option "alter materialized view view_name refresh on demand" force the view to refresh before the operation completes?

Comment: @Paul - [from the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_2002.htm#i2226546): "This clause only sets the default refresh options. For instructions on actually implementing the refresh, refer to ...", which suggests not. I haven't verified though.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! If you've got any insights on my question I'd greatly appreciate them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40484564/oracle-11g-broken-materliazed-view-stop-refresh-without-dropping-view-or-refres