# Oracle 11g Broken Materialized view: Stop refresh without dropping view or refreshing view?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

So I've got a materalized view (I know...) :

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW vw_my_view_here
REFRESH COMPLETE START WITH SYSDATE NEXT SYSDATE + 1/24 AS 
/*huge-ass select statement here*/
UNION ALL
/*huge-ass select statement here*/
UNION ALL
/*huge-ass select statement here*/
UNION ALL
/*huge-ass select statement here*/
```

This has been present in our system for some time without causing issues. One of these select queries is broken (somehow - presumibly schema changes in the underlying tables) and has taken to running for 24 hours straight and consuming all of the boxes resources. This is a problem for the other things on the box.

I can't drop or modify the view - as it's completely undocumented (I know...) and I need to figure out who consumes it, how it's populated, etc. first.

I tried killing the process that's handling the query, but it seems another query is fired straight away afterwards.

How can I stop the materialized view without 1) dropping the view and (2) without refreshing the view (because that's taking 24+ hours and all of our box resources).

I've tried running

```
 alter materialized view view_name refresh on demand;
```

but it seems to just run endlessly with no effect on the original massive query.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you killed the current refresh processes (not sure that sounds like a great idea, but...) while the `alter` is running? I suspect it's waiting for the current refresh to finish before it can actually change the refresh period, rather than trying to refresh itself.

Comment: Since you didn't specify `on commit` or `on demand` (and especially since you have a `start with`) your mview is already refreshing on demand. Is there a scheduled job set up to do the refresh? If so, try disabling that.

Comment: @AlexPoole You nailed it in one. Killing the refreshing process while the 'refresh on demand;' command was running resolved the issue. 
The processes queuing didn't even occur to me, so the behavior seemed so confusing. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Boneist it seems that managing to set the materialized view to 'refresh on demand' resolved the issue. does 'REFRESH COMPLETE START WITH SYSDATE NEXT SYSDATE + 1/24 AS ' not set the view to refresh at intervals like I thought?

Comment: @Paul sorry, apologies; I didn't spot the "next" clause was specified too. Duh! In which case, I was wrong - altering it to be on demand would stop the automatic refreshes from taking place.

Comment: @Boneist thanks again for clarifying - one last question - how often would "SYSDATE NEXT SYSDATE + 1/24" make the refresh run - every hour/day? I'm not familiar with the syntax...

Comment: @Paul it would be every hour. Date intervals are measured in days, so an hour is 1/24th of a day.

Comment: @Boneist Brilliant - thanks a million!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [altering the refresh settings](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_2002.htm#i2226546) says:

> This clause only sets the default refresh options. For instructions on actually implementing the refresh, refer to Oracle Database Advanced Replication and Oracle Database Data Warehousing Guide.

So your `alter materialized view` statement is not doing a refresh itself. It is just waiting for the currently-excuting refresh to complete before it can update the data dictionary for that view. Once the current refresh completes (or is terminated) the `alter` will complete and prevent further automatic refreshes from being started.

Comment: Terminating the current query-process *while* the 'refresh on demand' was running (or more specifically, while it was waiting to run) - so that the refresh settings was updated before the update tried again - was the solution that worked for me. You have a very good nose for these things! Thank you again!